# Java 8e: Logic error and Array Index out of bounds Exception in a program

Tags: java, arrays

So i have written this piece of code for a class project, and it has two issues.

1. When run, displays is a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
2. The program does not function properly when run (detailed below) Currently i cannot identify either the exception, or the logic error.

It may be possible that the two are related. Help is humbly requested :)

The program should take 10 input values, then separate them by weather or not they are negative, odd or even. These values should be put into arrays, and the values of the arrays should be outputted as 3 separate columns, with the number of rows limited by the length of the longest array. Currently with the input values of `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 -3 -2 -1` the output is 1 row, reading `-2 -1 -1`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class APComSci9p1 {//Start program


    public static void main(String[] args) {//Start Main

    //Initilize inputs
    Scanner scnKey = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Initialize Arrays
    int[] aOriginValues,
          aEvenList,
          aOddList,
          aNegitiveList;

    aOriginValues = new int[10];
    aEvenList = new int[10];
    aOddList = new int[10];
    aNegitiveList = new int[10];

    //Initialize Array index Variables
    int iInput;
    int iListControlE = 0;
    int iListControlO = 0;
    int iListControlN = 0;

    //Start Loop
    for (iInput = 0; iInput <= 9; iInput++){
        System.out.print("Input value: ");
        aOriginValues[iInput] = scnKey.nextInt();

            //Start if/else
            if ((aOriginValues[iInput] % 2) == 0){
                aEvenList[iListControlE] = aOriginValues[iInput]; 
            }else {
                aOddList[iListControlO] = aOriginValues[iInput];
            }//end if/Else
            if (aOriginValues[iInput] < 0){
                aNegitiveList[iListControlN] = aOriginValues[iInput];
            }//end if
        }//End loop

    //Initialize Loop Specific variables
    int iLimit;

    //Start if/else #2
    if((aEvenList.length >= aOddList.length) && (aEvenList.length >= aNegitiveList.length)){
        iLimit = aEvenList.length;
    }else if((aOddList.length >= aEvenList.length) && (aOddList.length >= aNegitiveList.length)){
        iLimit = aOddList.length;
    }else{
        iLimit = aNegitiveList.length;
    }//End if/else #2

    System.out.println("    Even        Odd       Negitive  ");
    for (int iControl = 0; iControl <= iLimit; iControl ++){
        System.out.printf("%,12d%,11d%,12d%n", aEvenList[iControl], aOddList[iControl], aNegitiveList[iControl]);
    }

    }//End Main    
}//End program
```

Comment: The stack trace of the exception also tells you the line number where it happens. You are trying to access index 10 in an array that does not have this index.

Comment: I realize what the error is saying, i just cannot find where it is happening. To me (a biased source i know) i cannot see where i am referencing an index of 10 in a array with 10 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `aEvenList[iListControlE]` should actually be `aEvenList[iListControlE++]` similarly other arrays countor are not set correctly.
2. Your iLimit value is incorrectly being set.

The correct version is below,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class APComSci9p1 {// Start program

    public static void main(String[] args) {// Start Main

        // Initilize inputs
        Scanner scnKey = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Initialize Arrays
        int[] aOriginValues, aEvenList, aOddList, aNegitiveList;

        aOriginValues = new int[10];
        aEvenList = new int[10];
        aOddList = new int[10];
        aNegitiveList = new int[10];

        // Initialize Array index Variables
        int iInput;
        int iListControlE = 0;
        int iListControlO = 0;
        int iListControlN = 0;

        // Start Loop
        for (iInput = 0; iInput <= 9; iInput++) {
            System.out.print("Input value: ");
            aOriginValues[iInput] = scnKey.nextInt();

            // Start if/else
            if ((aOriginValues[iInput] % 2) == 0) {
                aEvenList[iListControlE++] = aOriginValues[iInput];
            } else {
                aOddList[iListControlO++] = aOriginValues[iInput];
            } // end if/Else
            if (aOriginValues[iInput] < 0) {
                aNegitiveList[iListControlN++] = aOriginValues[iInput];
            } // end if
        } // End loop

        // Initialize Loop Specific variables
        int iLimit;

        // Start if/else #2
        if ((iListControlE >= iListControlO)
                && (iListControlE >= iListControlN)) {
            iLimit = iListControlE;
        } else if ((iListControlO >= iListControlE)
                && (iListControlO >= iListControlN)) {
            iLimit = iListControlO;
        } else {
            iLimit = iListControlN;
        } // End if/else #2

        System.out.println("    Even        Odd       Negitive  ");
        for (int iControl = 0; iControl <= iLimit; iControl++) {
            System.out.printf("%,12d%,11d%,12d%n", aEvenList[iControl],
                    aOddList[iControl], aNegitiveList[iControl]);
        }

    }// End Main
}// End program
```

In general, you should learn how to debug your application.

Comment: You forgot to place `iListControlO` in place of `aOddList.length` inside `if` clause and similarly for other vars to set value of iLimit.

Comment: Thank you! Now, why do both edits work? I was unaware that adding the ++ was necessary for this problem. Similarly, what you did to redefine `iLimit` is making little sense to me right now.